# linux: alarm function doesn't work sometimes?

Tags: linux, signals, alarm

My code is as follows,The first time ,alarm works very well and handler2() function can work. however, the alarm doesn't work after it implement "doMain()" in the "handler2()".

I mean after the second time print ""In main Pleasae input: \n"", handler2() doesn't wrok anymore.

I don't know why? My code as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

#define MAX_LEN_COMM 64
jmp_buf jumper;


int stop =0; //o is not stop ,otherwise is stop;
void hanlder2();
void doMain();

void handler2()

{


    int len_command = 0;
    char character;
    char commandStr[60];
    printf("******************************\n");
    printf("In Alarm Pleasae input: \n");
    while((character=getchar())!='\n')
    {

        commandStr[len_command]=character;
        len_command++;
    }
    commandStr[len_command]='\0';
    printf("In Alarm input is %s\n",commandStr);
    if (strcmp(commandStr,"N")==0||strcmp(commandStr,"n")==0){
        printf("In Alarm You put no, we will stop alarm \n");
        stop=1;
        longjmp(jumper, 2);



    }
    else if(strcmp(commandStr,"Y")==0||strcmp(commandStr,"y")==0){
        printf("In Alarm You put yes, we will continue alarm \n");
        signal(SIGALRM, handler2); 
        alarm(5);

        doMain();




    }


}

void doMain(){
    while(1){
        setjmp(jumper);
        if(stop==0){
            signal(SIGALRM, handler2); 

            printf("return time %d\n",alarm(5));
        }
        int len_command = 0;
        char character;
        char commandStr[60];
        printf("In main Pleasae input: \n");
        while((character=getchar())!='\n')
        {

            commandStr[len_command]=character;
            len_command++;
        }
        commandStr[len_command]='\0';
        printf("In main input is %s\n",commandStr);
        if (strcmp(commandStr,"N")==0||strcmp(commandStr,"n")==0){
            printf("In main You put no\n");

        }
        else if(strcmp(commandStr,"Y")==0||strcmp(commandStr,"y")==0){
            printf("In main You put yes\n");

        }
    }


}


void main()
{
    doMain();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is very wrong.

First, the signature of the handler should be `void handler(int sig)`.

Second, there are very few functions that are safe to use within a handler so you should try to get out of a handler as quickly as possible and definitely not doing console i/o. You are using several unsafe library functions.

Lastly a signal handler is a function.  It runs and returns to where your program was interrupted by the signal.  During the time a handler runs signals *of the same type* are not deliverd.  By calling `doMain()` from the handler - which is crazy - the handler never ends.  Because it doesn't end you won't see any more alarm signals.

Comment: it's interesting that even if you do ```exec``` within the signal handler, the signal delivery remains blocked.